# ошибка 404 при запуске spring-boot приложения

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-boot

Здравствуйте!
Приложение запускается без ошибок стартером Идеи Maven.
При запуске этого же приложения стартером Идеи Spring Вoot выдается 404 ошибка.
Подскажите что надо подкрутить чтобы запустить конфигурацию Spring Boot?

[image: Конфигурация Run/Debug]

Проект и лог запуска можно посмотреть [здесь](https://yadi.sk/d/lkytOTdx3Ld9QV) .

Чат со службой поддержки JetBrains [здесь](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-176905).

Comment: надо посмотреть в лог на предмет ошибок и пр.

Comment: ваш комментарий не добавляет почти ничего к пониманию вашей проблемы

Comment: Дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно [рекомендациям по ведению дискуссий на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6)б ссылки могут служить только дополнением.